# Перестает работать скрипт JQuery

Tags: jquery

В коде страницы подключен скрипт, который добавляет класс active к диву, на который наведена мышка

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                                $("div.right div.floatbox").hover(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                    });
                }); 
</script>
```

плюс еще подключается слайдер carousel http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/netcat_template/jquery/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
        {
            // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
            carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
            carousel.clip.hover(function() {
                carousel.stopAuto();
            }, function() {
                carousel.startAuto();
            });
        };

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            auto: 2,
            wrap: 'circular',
            scroll: 1,
            visible: 1,
            animation: 5000,
            buttonNextHTML: null,
            buttonPrevHTML: null,
            initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
            itemFallbackDimension: 100
                  });
                });

        </script>

<!-- Стили для слайдера -->
<style type="text/css">
    div#teaser {
        overflow: hidden;

    }
    .teaser-link {
        width: 628px;
    }

    .mycarousel-style {
        width: 628px;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

html-код

```
<div class="page_margins"><div id="teaser-box"><div id="teaser">

         <!-- Слайдер -->
         <div class="left">
          <ul id="mycarousel" class="mycarousel-style"><li>
          <div class="teaser-link">
            <h3><a href="/">СКИДКИ ДО 20%</a></h3>
            <p>В этом слайдере можно выводить информацию актуальных акциях, специальных предложениях и т.д. <a href="/">Подробнее</a></p>
          </div>
            <img src="/images/image.jpg" height="318" width="628" /></li></ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Акции и предложения -->

        <div class="right">

          <h2>Акции и предложения</h2>

          <div class="news-teaser floatbox">
              <a href="/news/news_3.html" class="preview icaption_left"><img src="images/teaser-news.jpg" alt="teaser-news.jpg, 2,3kB" title="Teaser news" border="0" height="54" width="74"></a>
            <span class="date"> 31 августа 2012</span>  <h3><a href="/news/news_4.html">Реорганизация предприятия</a></h3>
          </div>

          <div class="news-teaser floatbox active">
            <a href="/news/news_3.html" class="preview icaption_left"><img src="images/teaser-news.jpg" alt="teaser-news.jpg, 2,3kB" title="Teaser news" border="0" height="54" width="74"></a>
            <span class="date"> 31 августа 2012</span>  <h3><a href="/news/news_4.html">Реорганизация предприятия</a></h3>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div></div></div>
```

после подключения скрипта слайдера-карусели, скрипт, добавляющий класс к диву, перестает работать. Подскажите, чем это может быть вызвано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) в помощь

Comment: пробовала, не помогает.

Comment: что в консоли при загрузке?

Comment: в какой консоли? вы имеете виду файербаг?

Comment: именно его

Comment: большое спасибо, оказалось, слой со слайдером-каруселью оказался выше чем слой, где к диву добавляется класс active, поэтому функция hover не срабатывала. все поправили)